# Get-VM without showing results

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I want to run a test to see if a VM already exists in hyper-v

Here is what I have:

```
$VM = "DC"
$VMName = Get-VM -name $VM
if (!$VMname) { 
Write-Host "No VM named $VM exists" }
else
{ Write-Host "A VM named $VM already exists" }
```

However if the VM doesn't exist, it throws this error

```
PS C:\Users\sowen> $VMName = Get-VM -name $VM
Get-VM : A parameter is invalid. Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name DC.
At line:1 char:11
+ $VMName = Get-VM -name $VM
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (DC:String) [Get-VM], VirtualizationInvalidArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVMCommand

                                                                                                          How could I silently find if a VM already exists on HyperV with powershell?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848479.aspx) Get-VM supports common parameters. Using `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` might be a cleaner way to accomplish the same thing

```
$VMName = Get-VM -name $VM -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Or just a simple try/catch would do the trick as well. I would just use the code above with a simple `If($VMName){}` to account for the null return.